# Need a work around for reportValidity()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I wrote a custom javascript/jQuery validation function in .submit and I use the reportValidity function() to get those tooltip bubbles, but learned during development that it was only working fully in Opera and Chrome.  Apparently, reportValidity() does not work in IE, Safari, and FF the same way.

In FF, it will at least take the user to the incomplete question, but does not provide an automatic tooltip like chrome and opera does to inform the user.

Safari and IE are clearly validating correctly, but without any indication of any portion being incomplete.

What is the work around for this, i.e. a way to get similar behavior as Chrome or Opera?

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I did:

```
document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].setCustomValidity("Please fill out at least one of these fields.");
    try {
        document.forms[0].reportValidity();
    }
    catch (e){ //for browsers that don't support reportValidity
        $($('input')[0]).popover({
            placement:'right',
            trigger:'manual',
            html:true,
            content:'Please fill out at least one of these fields.'
        });
        $($('input')[0]).popover('show');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $($('input')[0]).popover('hide');
        }, 4000);
    }
    finally{
        return false;
    }
```

You can obviously tune the 4 second timeout to meet your needs, or replace it with something else entirely, but the workaround part with the try-catch and popover seemed to do well for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a way to test this as I no longer have access to that product.

Comment: hahah i guess I can go implement something similar real fast and give it a go

Comment: Just sharing in case others come upon your question - up to you!

Comment: This works very well for me, good job.  However, I have a problem where the popover content does not update when the method is called more than once (i.e. if validation fails twice but for a different reason, the old popup error is shown except from the new one on the second occasion).  Is there a way to force the popover text to update / recreate the object?

Comment: I think it would be best to decide which of the two validations is more important, then show that one first. Otherwise you could try to use string concatenation to add the "please fill out at least one of these fields" to the existing validity message.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue in one of our project that also needed to be accessible and therefore support screen readers - an issue that most solutions completely ignore.

Because the great thing with `reportValidity` is that it is recognized by screen readers (like Jaws) too, while adding some HTML elements yourself usually isn't.

We created the following polyfill for the method:

```
if (!HTMLInputElement.prototype.reportValidity) {
    HTMLInputElement.prototype.reportValidity = function () {
        if (this.checkValidity()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert(this.validationMessage);
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

It simply checks if the method is supported by the browser (IE as we know does not) and if not it adds a method that shows an alert box with the validation message. The alert box is recognized by the screen reader.

Instead of an alert box one could for instance also display a DIV (or something else) that is marked as an [ARIA-live region](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions).